# Rate of flow and time taken

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A cylinder have 4 holes at a distance of $\frac 34$, $\frac 12, \frac 14$ from the bottom and the 4th hole at bottom. From each hole water flows at rate of $2\frac{L}{min}$. If the cylinder has $120L$, in how many minutes will the cylinder be empty?

Comment: How is this number theory?

Comment: Is this number theory because we count "one, two, three...four holes!", or why?

Answer (score 3):

Originally, there are four holes and so water is flowing out at a rate of $8$ L/min. This lasts until the tank is three-quarters full (i.e. it has lost $30$ L), which takes $30/8 = 3.75$ minutes.

Then there are three holes, so water is flowing out at a rate of $6$ L/min, which lasts for another $30$ liters. This takes $30/6 = 5$ minutes. Now continue the process.